# Get literal command line of PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, command-line

For reasons involving privilege elevation, I need to be able to invoke a script in exactly the same way as it was initially run. For this reason, I want to be able to retrieve the literal, complete, unprocessed command line used to originally invoke a script. Optimally, this would behave like:

```
# DoIt.ps1
Get-CommandLine | Write-Output
```

---

```
PS> ./DoIt.ps1 -Something something abc 123
./DoIt.ps1 -Something something abc 123
```

---

```
C:\> PowerShell.exe ./DoIt.ps1 -Something something abc 123
./DoIt.ps1 -Something something abc 123
```

But I can deal with keeping `PowerShell.exe`, and obviously it doesn't have to be a single cmdlet.

Comment: Don't forget to ask your question.

Comment: You may want to have a look at `$MyInvocation`

Comment: To add to what Mathias commented, you specifically want the `Line` property.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have no idea why I didn't think to look at `$MyInvocation`.

Comment: @AlexanderMartin Don't forget to post an answer with your solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As advised by [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) and [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician), I found that `$MyInvocation.Line` provides exactly what I'm looking for. Don't know why Google didn't help, but I found the answer.